# Kernel panic. Cannot install Ubuntu

Tags: kernel

I started  Ubuntu installation from bootable flash drive. But after 2-3 steps, just before the partitioning step, some error occurred and installation exited. After that every time I start installation, it doesn't start and shows something like this .

`Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block`

Please need help ASAP

Comment: Better to redo that USB stick. It's probably corrupt.

Comment: Yes. I formatted that usb, and again put linux on it. It worked. Thanks